# Selenium, click submit button with no id python

Tags: python, selenium, button, submit

I'm struggling to figure a way to click the submit button in the following class. It does not contain an ID, name, or any easily identifiable method that is not dynamically generated. any help is appreciated.

so far i have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='button-status-container'][@type='submit']")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='button-status-container']//button-status-container[@type='submit']")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button-status-container[type="button"]')
```

all of the above errors out with `NoSuchElementException`. 
[the htlm of submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVPIY.png)

Comment: try following xpath: '//div/button[contains(text(), 'Register')]'

Comment: Can you provide bigger part of html on that page for verification ? In text - not screenshot.

Comment: @Poloq you solution worked, i had to find all elements with 'Register', append to list, and select the correct one:    register_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Register')]")
    register_button[2].click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct xpath/css selector should be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='button-status-container']/button[@type='submit']")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button-status-container > [type="button"]')
```